# GraphQL - Failed to load schema from http://localhost:5555/graphql: fetch failed

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to use this [boilerplate project](https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate).

My codegen.yml file defines the schema as:

```
schema: http://localhost:5555/graphql
```

When I try to generate the graphql code-gen, I get an error that says:

```
> yarn run v1.22.18 $ DEBUG=true graphql-codegen   ✔ Parse configuration
> ❯ Generate outputs
>     ❯ Generate src/lib/graphql.tsx
>       ⠙ Load GraphQL schemas
>         Load GraphQL documents
>         Generate TypeError: fetch failed
>     at Object.processResponse (/test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:200:23)
>     at /test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:941:38
>     at node:internal/process/task_queues:141:7
>     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)
>     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:138:8)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   cause: Error: connect
> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5555
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
>     errno: -61,   ✔ Parse configuration   ❯ Generate outputs
>     ❯ Generate src/lib/graphql.tsx
>       ✖ Load GraphQL schemas
>         → Failed to load schema
>         Load GraphQL documents
>         Generate
> 
> 
>  Found 1 error
> 
>   ✖ src/lib/graphql.tsx
>     Failed to load schema from http://localhost:5555/graphql:
> 
>         fetch failed
>         TypeError: fetch failed
>     at Object.processResponse (/test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:200:23)
>     at /test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:941:38
>     at node:internal/process/task_queues:141:7
>     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)
>     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:138:8)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> 
>         GraphQL Code Generator supports:
>           - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
>           - Introspection JSON File
>           - URL of GraphQL endpoint
>           - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)
>           - String in config file
> 
>         Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.
>     Error: Failed to load schema
>         at loadSchema (/test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:509:15)
>         at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1039:65
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1038:52
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:925:21
>     Error: Failed to load schema
>         at loadSchema (/test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:509:15)
>         at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1039:65
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1038:52
>         at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:925:21
> 
> 
> Running lifecycle hook "afterStart" scripts... [CLI] Loading Schemas
> [CLI] Exited with an error DetailedError: Failed to load schema
>     at loadSchema (/test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:509:15)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>     at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1039:65
>     at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:1038:52
>     at async /test/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js:925:21 {   details: '\n' +
>     '        Failed to load schema from http://localhost:5555/graphql:\n' +
>     '\n' +
>     '        fetch failed\n' +
>     '        TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
>     '    at Object.processResponse (/test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:200:23)\n'
> +
>     '    at /test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:941:38\n'
> +
>     '    at node:internal/process/task_queues:141:7\n' +
>     '    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)\n' +
>     '    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:138:8)\n' +
>     '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n' +
>     '    \n' +
>     '        GraphQL Code Generator supports:\n' +
>     '          - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")\n' +
>     '          - Introspection JSON File\n' +
>     '          - URL of GraphQL endpoint\n' +
>     '          - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)\n' +
>     '          - String in config file\n' +
>     '    \n' +
>     '        Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.\n' +
>     '    \n' +
>     '      ',   source: 'src/lib/graphql.tsx',   context: [Object: null prototype] {} } Something went wrong Failed to load schema for
> "src/lib/graphql.tsx"
>         Failed to load schema from http://localhost:5555/graphql:
> 
>         fetch failed
>         TypeError: fetch failed
>     at Object.processResponse (/test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:200:23)
>     at /test/node_modules/cross-undici-fetch/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/index.js:941:38
>     at node:internal/process/task_queues:141:7
>     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:201:9)
>     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:138:8)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>     
>         GraphQL Code Generator supports:
>           - ES Modules and CommonJS exports (export as default or named export "schema")
>           - Introspection JSON File
>           - URL of GraphQL endpoint
>           - Multiple files with type definitions (glob expression)
>           - String in config file
>     
>         Try to use one of above options and run codegen again.
```

I have seen [this github issue](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/7396) which indicates that some people with this problem found a resolution by deleting their yarn.lock file and re-running yarn. I have tried this twice (the second time I also deleted the node modules folder at the root directory level) and still get the same issue.

I don't know what to try next. I don't understand what is failing or why. Can anyone suggest the next thing to try to solve this connection issue?

When I try to run the local version, the front end loads at localhost3000, but at localhost:5555/graphql, I get a response that says:

> GET query missing.

When I inspect the console on that page, it says 'bad request'

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise I had to have the server running to run the codegen. It works.